# Apache not accessible from the outside world, working internally

Tags: apache, http, ip

I have installed apache xampp and all working internally.
I then redirected port 8080 and the ip address on the router to the internal ip address of the server. I can see the nat take place and on the server I can see the httpd.exe coming through but cannot connect from outside world.

```
Listen 192.168.0.47:8080
ServerAdmin postmaster@192.168.0.47
ServerName 192.168.0.47:8080
DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/xampp/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI


    AllowOverride All


    Require all granted

</Directory>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/xampp/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>
<Directory "/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Listen 192.168.0.47:8080
```

Should be

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Your only listening to requests that come though a local IP

Comment: Or just `Listen 8080` will work too.

Comment: Removed upvote as you're using wrong port. OP is serving on `8080` but you're telling him to listen on `80`.

Comment: Yeah i change it from * to 0.0.0.0 - accidently knocked off port too

Comment: Re added upvote, though he needs to remove `ServerName` directive too.

Comment: Made that change but still not connecting.

Comment: When changes are made you need to restart apache

Comment: I restarted but cannot connect. I can see through netstat -a that its listening. Log shows nothing of any data coming from the live IP address.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change these three lines:

```
Listen 192.168.0.47:8080
ServerAdmin postmaster@192.168.0.47
ServerName 192.168.0.47:8080
```

to just this:

```
Listen 8080
```

Right now your server is only listening for connections on `192.168.0.47`, an external connection will come to your ISP IP address.

You don't need `ServerName` unless using [URLs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) to connect. This tells the server to look for a HTTP_HOST of `192.168.0.47` so your Apache will deny requests to your external IP.

Comment: Made the changes and restarted apache server but still not working from the outside.

Comment: Check `/var/log/apache2/errors.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log` (or wherever your logs are). If there are lines here, it means Apache is getting a connection, if not then it probably isn't.

Comment: This line `container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.` seems like it's part of a comment block. Did you remove the comment and leave this in by accident?

Comment: The httpd.conf has a line Error "logs/error.log" This folder is in c:\xampp\apache\logs

Comment: OK, so check that document as well as access.log and tell me if you see anything.

Comment: Checked and nothing showing and no errors. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: The issue is probably networking related then, rather than Apache related. Try re-posting the question on [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Comment: Thanks Oshawott. I am running filezilla internally and it works ok. I will post on Server fault. Just wondering if it's a default route on the server that is throwing off the reply back to the gateway.

Comment: Got it working. Forced a route on the server to the gateway and now I have access. Great many thanks again. now the next stage getting phplist working.

Comment: How did you do this ? Forced a route on the server to the gateway

Comment: I just launched aws instance with ubutu 18.* and my apache is not accessable from outside/publicly via ip... following is settings of apache2.conf:

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: In which file should I make the change?